# Reduce github repository size by deleting commits

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

My github repository once had one commit with a very large executable inside, and some time later I realized this takes me (and other people) huge of time to clone it from anywhere, so I deleted this executable and do the git rebase, and I'm now 100% sure that there're no large files in the current commits. However the previous releases were using the code before the rebase (although the file contents are exactly the same after the rebase), thus github still keeps the reference to those commits. I tested on a private repository without any releases, and I find that the repository size goes back to normal after rebase. My main repository has > 700 stars and I don't want to make a new one. Is there anything I can do to reduce the git clone size? Deleting all the releases is OK for me, but only in the case that it will solve this problem (which I'm not sure). Here's my repository https://github.com/SUSYUSTC/MathTranslate

I tried to do this rebase but not working.

Comment: I successfully solved this problem by deleting all the related releases and tags.